# Problem with installing Tex Live for LaTeX workshop

Tags: tex-core

I was hoping to turn my VS Code into a TeX / LaTeX editor. I came across an extension called LaTeX workshop which told me I had to install Tex Live. Once I downloaded the installer my AV told me it was safe but windows defender still blocked it. I am using Windows 10.
[image]

This is the link that I clicked on to download TeX Live.

[image]

On the TeX live website I clicked on download.

[image]

Then I downloaded the installer. My windows defender stopped me from opening it though.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is really a Windows thing - you'll need to tell Defender to allow the file through.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So there is no other way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: this is not 'fixable' at the TeX side. If you cannot for some reason disable Defender here, you could try MiKTeX (an alternative TeX distribution) or go with a purely online setup such as Overleaf.

Comment: Yes I have heard of MikTeX and I do use Overleaf at the moment, but I thought MikTeX would not work with TeX workshop